# How SQL server handles updates to a temp table (in regards to disk access)

Tags: sql-server, performance, temp-tables

Let's say we have MS SQL Server database and table A in it. Then, we perform something like this:

```
select A.a1 
into #temp1
from A
```

This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305977/en-us) says: "If memory is available, both table variables and temporary tables are created and processed while in memory (data cache)."

Let's say that we have 100 rows in #temp1, which easily fits into memory...so whole #temp1 is in memory now. But then, we execute this statement:

```
UPDATE #temp1 SET a1 = a1 + 1
```

Does this involve some IO operations? For example, is something written into temp_log (which is, I think, not in RAM)? Or perhaps, since we are doing update now, the whole #temp1 is moved to hdd...?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that no log is kept for temp tables, as tempdb is cleared on every restart.

Update:
Logging occurs in tempdb, but it is reduced: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms190768.aspx;

Perhaps a table-valued variable is suitable instead of a table in tempdb:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

Comment: I think that log is kept for temp tables. What is the purpose of temp table log file if statements are not logged?

Comment: We are both (sort of) correct. Logging occurs in tempdb, but it is reduced: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms190768.aspx;

Comment: Note that [table variables use tempdb](http://cybersql.blogspot.com/2009/12/yes-table-variables-and-temp-tables.html)

Comment: So, that answers my question: "there is some IO at least for log", but is table still in memory? Regarding table variables, they are not logged, for sure, and if they fit in memory, everything is fine...but if you try to perform some more complex update (not like the one in my example), you will probably need indexes, which you can't create on table variables.

Comment: Since tempdb actions are minimally logged information will be logged to allow the transaction to be rolled back, but that's the extent of the log I/O cost. Whether there will be I/O involved in the update is dependent on the space in memory available. Writes to tempdb will only occur if there is not enough room in memory to house the result set or if it would be more efficient (parallelism, etc).